# How do I remove an app drawer button without removing an app drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, launcher, google-now, rooted-device

currently I’m working on a live wallpaper in which I have a app drawer button , but I am unable to give it permissions and unable to remove the main app drawer button.

How do I make work the above app drawer button & remove the original one.[replacing original app drawer by new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21UPx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` to false

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```